# Специализации шаблона и реализация методов класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Доброго времени суток!

Встретил подобный код

```
template<class T>
class Test
{
    static T test();
};

typedef Test<int> FirstTest;
typedef Test<long> SecondTest;

int FirstTest::test()
{
    return 10;
}

long SecondTest::test()
{
    return UL;
}
```

gcc 4.4 выдает ошибку: too few template-parameter-lists

Но студия это как-то съела. Помогите разобраться

Comment: Что, даже это съела?

      return UL;

Comment: нет, это очепятка :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так методы не обозначены, как шаблонные же

```
template<> // here
int FirstTest::test()
{
    return 10;
}
template<> // ...and here
long SecondTest::test()
{
    return UL; // ???
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kwyxac18.aspx

**UPD:**

http://ideone.com/Gxb3OE

Comment: спасибо) уже также решил вопрос. все верно. UL - очепятка :)